# What does variable declaration with multiple comma separated values mean (e.g. var a = b,c,d;)

Tags: javascript, variables

When I try to understand plugin codes, I often find these kind of declarations but I don't know exactly what it means.

var a = b,c,d;

Comment: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score 34):

This is a syntactic shorthand, and  identical to:

```
var a = b;
var c;
var d;
```

The first one (a) gets initialized with the value of b, but c and d are uninitialized.

Comment: @DarylMacam - You might want to accept this answer if you found it helping.

Answer (score 0):

It will define `var a = b` and then define var c and d

Comment: Yes. `a` is declared and given a value of `b`, and `c` and `d` are declared with no value whatsoever.