# What means this jquery code with two values in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found an example for solve a problem I had but there are a line that I don't know what it means or how it works:

```
var target = $(e.target), article;
```

Can anyone explain it to me? Thank you!

Comment: Declaring 2 variables. Assigning value to the first 1

Comment: Duplicate of [What does variable declaration with multiple comma separated values mean (e.g. var a = b,c,d;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076750/what-does-variable-declaration-with-multiple-comma-separated-values-mean-e-g-v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring two variables and the first one has a value.

```
var target = $(e.target), article;
```

is the same as:

```
var target = $(e.target);
var article;
```

This not jQuery related -- rather "vanilla" Javascript.

Helpful material: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var