# R Notebook HTML Format - add hyperlinks to paged table

Tags: r, hyperlink, html-table, r-markdown, rnotebook

I wish to knit an html file from an R Notebook that contains paged tables with hyperlinks.
Hyperlinks can be inserted using `knitr::kable`, but I can't find a way to generate a ***paged*** table with this function.
Paged tables are the default notebook output, but I can't find a way of inserting functional ***hyperlinks***. Many thanks for your help.

````
---
title: "Paged notebook table with hyperlinks"
output:
  html_notebook:
    code_folding: "hide"
---

```{r rows.print=3}
wiki.url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
df1 <- data.frame(Month=month.name, URL=paste0("[", month.name, "](", wiki.url, month.name, ")"))
df2 <- data.frame(Month=month.name, URL=paste0("<a href='", wiki.url, month.name, "'>", month.name, "</a>"))
print(df1)
```

```{r rows.print=3}
print(df2)
```

```{r rows.print=3}
knitr::kable(df1)
```

```{r rows.print=3}
knitr::kable(df2)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a perfect solution to my problem, I thought I'd post the workaround that I came up with - in case someone has a similar problem.
I created the table plus hyperlinks with `knitr::kable` and then added an html button and [inline javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show) to toggle visibility - not as elegant as a paged table, but does the job.
Note the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the file that [hides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644673/hide-all-elements-with-class-using-plain-javascript) tables by default.
(*Paste code into an .Rmd file in RStudio*):

````
---
title: "Managing large tables with hyperlinks in html notebook"
output:
  html_notebook:
    code_folding: "hide"
---

<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>

```{r}
library(knitr)
df1 <- data.frame(Month=month.name, Link=paste0("[", month.name, "](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", month.name, ")"))
```

<button class="button" onclick="myFunction('DIV_months')">Show/hide table</button>
<div id="DIV_months" class="div_default_hide">
```{r}
knitr::kable(df1)
```
</div>

<script>
var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("div_default_hide");
for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++)
    {
    divsToHide[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
````