# Is it possible to disable the share Button from outside?

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I'm disabling the share button from inside of `photoswipe-ui-default.js` file right now. However I'm wondering whether there is a posibility to do it from outside of that code?

Comment: Which code? Please write more context of your problem

Comment: Should I add the entire code of the PhotoSwipe library here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would just disable it through the options listed in the documentation: https://photoswipe.com/documentation/options.html

[image: Image of documentation]

Otherwise you could do the following:

```js
<script>
var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("pswp__button pswp__button--share"); //divsToHide is an array
for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
    divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "hidden"; // or
    divsToHide[i].style.display = "none"; // depending on what you're doing
}
</script>
```

Taken from: [Hide all elements with class using plain Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644673/hide-all-elements-with-class-using-plain-javascript)

Comment: Yes I was looking for the first solution. I've just somehow overseen that options object can be used for it. Thanks!