# I tried using style.display = "none"; for Javascript to hide my video tag, but that is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to hide the video element using javascript by using [videoclass].style.display = "none"; but it is not working.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video class="dntshow" width="444" height="250" controls>
  <source src="" id="video_here">
    Your browser can not play this video.
</video>
```

CSS:

```
.dntshow{
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}
```

JS:

```
var doshow = document.getElementsByClassName("dntshow");
 doshow.style.display = "none";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JuicyYellow getElementsByClassName gives you an array like structure so you can use [0] index like this var doshow = document.getElementsByClassName("dntshow")[0];
or you can use querySelector(".dntshow")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `getElementsByClassName` gives you a list of founded DOM-elements and you just need one, so take the first one. Otherwise you could take `getElementById` and use an id instead of classname, so you get only one.

Try this:

```
var doshow = document.getElementsByClassName("dntshow")[0];
doshow.style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements matching the query. You need to get the element you're hiding from it. For example, if it's the first element, try this:

```
var doshow = document.getElementsByClassName("dntshow")[0];
doshow.style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

*[Hide all elements with class using plain Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644673/hide-all-elements-with-class-using-plain-javascript)*

```
<script>
var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("classname"); //divsToHide is an array
for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
    divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "hidden"; // or
    divsToHide[i].style.display = "none"; // depending on what you're doing
}
```