How to *disable* copy button in README.md code blocks on GitHub?
On a README.md that i'm currently authoring the copy button really gets in the way in the Editor Preview, often hiding parts of the code:

And once committed, the copy button takes up extra space:

Both cases i really don't like. Is there a way to disable the copy button on code blocks?

On gh-pages? It's kramdown, so you can configure it not to. On Github itself? You don't, you have no control over how Github styles markdown or which plugins it applies to all .md files

Where/How is that copy button located? (which tool do you use ?)

Note that the copy button is a right-aligned element though, and codeblocks are 100% width elements, so if it overlaps your code you may already be doing something odd: are you using HTML elements instead of code fences? What does your markdown look like? (and please remember to put that in your post)

@luuk Ah, it's actually only happening in the web edit preview, once it's commited it the button is out of the way: https://github.com/Philzen/rewrite-recipe-testng-to-junit-jupiter/blob/25c8f112287b90b2a70d40356c29caa1c69335c1/README.md#implementation-status … but it still behaves naughty, i'd prefer Github not to display it.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Not gh-pages, but on github repository / editor view. You may find the code here: github.com/Philzen/rewrite-recipe-testng-to-junit-jupiter/blob/… – but however it is structured actually does not change the gist of my question.

Please put that in your post, but again: if it's on github.com's own site, as part of browsing the repository, you have no control other than (and you should definitely do that here) sending a message to GH through https://support.github.com/?tags=dotcom-direct) to let github know their plugin has a problem given your use-case. You don't control what github does on its own website in this case, but you do control whether they take a feature change into consideration (I've filed many in the past, and pretty much all of them were taken on board. Just don't expect things to change immediately)

When using Edge (this might work in Chrome too), it can be done temporarily:

Open "Inspect" ( Ctrl+Shift+I)

Paste this in the console:

var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("octicon");
for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
      divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "hidden"; // or
      divsToHide[i].style.display = "none"; // depending on what you're doing
  }



P.S. The code was copied, with a small change, from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36384100/724039
EDIT: To make it, a bit, more safe, you can create two Bookmarklet's

From you favorites page (edge://favorites)
Create a new favorite named: "hide those things"   *)
In the URL paste this:
javascript:var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("octicon");for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){ var dummy =  divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "hidden"; }


Create a onother new favorite named: "show those things"   *)
In the URL paste this:
javascript:var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("octicon");for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){ var dummy =  divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "visible"; }



When you have created those links directly in the Favorites bar, the two new links are visible (when the favorites bar is visible), and can  be used to, temporarily, hide those copy Buttons. And they can be made visible by using the second link.
*= you can change the name to whatever you like

Thanks, but this is really not a solution. One can open DevTools on any web page and modify the hell out of it. This is a markdown / GFM question, the solution needs to be able to be committed.

I added an extra option, to make it (only a bit!) more safe. Until this is solved permanently you are always able to use this.
